# I need help on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a Json object in which I would like to fill a drop down list with distinct values selected from a field of my Json object

Comment: Don't you think that if the question text was in french the answer was expected in french ?

Comment: @tine Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please tell us a little bit more about your problem, providing more details about your JSON object, and what exactly you would like to do with it?

Comment: provide the JSON markup of the JSON object

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox, no, I don't think so. If the original question text was on some other language than English then this is not the site you have to post it to. SO uses only English and thanks God. Also reading the OPs question in French it doesn't make much more sense than currently :-) @tine post the JSON object.

Comment: ... as well as which fields/values you'd want to become options?

Comment: @tine - tine, connaissez-vous l'anglais? Nous avons du traduire votre question en anglais car Stack Overflow est une communauté anglophone. (et je m'excuse si mon français n'est pas très fort)

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen, I can hardly imagine a developer not speaking English.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - In retrospect, this is very true :D but I'd rather personally look like a fool than risk the entire SO community looking like an un-empathic exclusive anglos-only club to someone who's asking for help ;)

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen, there are rules, those rules should apply to everyone, otherwise we descent to anarchy (exaggerating of course). For what serve those rules if some people can make efforts and respect them while others don't? Also there are hundreds of other francophone sites out there where you could get help in French. If the question and the answer are on French this means that other people who don't speak French won't be able to understand neither of them. SO is a community site meaning that everyone should benefit from it and that's the beauty of it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Agreed, but for a new user with a language barrier, we have to make the effort to demonstrate that they are welcome, but that there are also rules. I feel it has to be made clear that the translation _isn't_ an attempt to alienate _them_; if they asked in French my first assumption isn't that they don't respect the rules but that they don't know English. Just 'cause English-less devs are rare doesn't mean they don't exist, nor that they don't count. If that _is_ the case (though unlikely) not explaining at least once in their language gives a very, _very_ negative impression.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen, good point, I agree with you. I'll try to be more tolerant to new users the next time.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - But they found the "Ask a Question" button... either my position _is_ a little silly or SO's UI design is flawless. :P

Comment: @Virtual @Richard @Darin: just for the record, folks: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/ is the official Non-English Question Policy for trilogy sites. Also see the [relevant meta q&a](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var s = [];
for (var n in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        s.push("<option value='");
        s.push(n);
        s.push("'>");
        s.push(obj[n]);
        s.push("</option>");
    }
}
$("select").append(s.join(""));
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using the "StringBuilder" style rather than straight concatenation?

Comment: @Bears will eat you - To keep things interesting.

Comment: @bears if he has a long list of items, chaos's way is going to be a LOT faster in older browsers (and in some newer ones) than straight string concatenation

Comment: @Bears, @Jason - Yep, depending on the implementation it should really cut down on the number of copies being made. *(Although for all we know, under the covers the strings could behave more like string builders for some implementations but I doubt that is the case.)*

Comment: @Chaos - I cant understand why you go halfway to a string builder solution then use + concatenation. Surely you should push each distinct string onto the array if you are concerned about this?

Comment: @James - That is because I am not really concerned about it but I will update to meet your standards. :)

Comment: @Jason - last time I tested (about a year ago), IE was the only browser in which "StringBuilder" is faster.

Comment: @bears i suggest you read this book then: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/059680279X?ie=UTF8&tag=nczonline-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=059680279X

Comment: @Jason - my copy arrived today :). Even better, I tested out the StringBuilder style vs concatenation in the same context as I did before, and StringBuilder == _much faster_.

Comment: @bears it's a great book, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = $('#select');
for (var n in obj) {
    myList.append($('<option></option>').val(obj[n]).text(n));
}
```